# pyTelegramBotAPI(telebot) обработка и прием запросов

Tags: python, handlers

Добрый день. Для начала приведу весь код моей программы, а затем задам вопросы по пунктам.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import config
import telebot
import MongoDB
from collections import OrderedDict

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
counter = 0
Group_id = None
Classes = []


@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def add(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите номер группы для добавления в базу данных")
    add_answer


@bot.message_handler(commands=['get'])
def get(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите номер группы")
    get_answer


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def get_answer(message):
    db = MongoDB.MongoDB(config.database_address)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, db.get(Group_id=message.text.upper()))
    return False


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def add_answer(message):
    global Group_id
    global counter
    global Classes
    if (counter == 0):
        Group_id = message.text.upper()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите расписание для " + config.Days_of_week_for_chat[0])
        counter += 1
        Classes.append(Group_id)
    elif (counter == 1):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите расписание для " + config.Days_of_week_for_chat[1])
        counter += 1
        Classes.append(message.text)
    elif (counter == 2):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите расписание для " + config.Days_of_week_for_chat[2])
        counter += 1
        Classes.append(message.text)
    elif (counter == 3):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите расписание для " + config.Days_of_week_for_chat[3])
        counter += 1
        Classes.append(message.text)
    elif (counter == 4):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите расписание для " + config.Days_of_week_for_chat[4])
        counter += 1
        Classes.append(message.text)
    elif (counter == 5):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите расписание для " + config.Days_of_week_for_chat[5])
        counter += 1
        Classes.append(message.text)
    elif (counter == 6):
        Classes.append(message.text)
        Schedule = OrderedDict()
        Temp = dict(zip(config.Days_of_week, Classes))
        for days in config.Days_of_week:
            Schedule[days] = Temp[days]
        db = MongoDB.MongoDB(config.database_address)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, db.insert(Group_id, Schedule))
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Первый вопрос: Как вы можете заметить, в функции add_answer(message) вопрос с добавлением значений по дням недели я решил через глобальную переменную. Если это единственный верный вариант в данном случае, то хорошо, но если есть более лаконичный способ, то расскажите о нем пожалуйста.
Данную проблему я пробовал решить и вот так:

```
for day in config.Days_of_week_for_chat:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите расписание для " + day)
```

но потерпел фиаско, так как бот выдал следующее:
[image: Фиаско]

В моем боте имеется две команды /get и /add. Если я использую команду /get, а затем /add, то сообщения продолжают обрабатываться /get. Иными словами вопрос в том как прекратить обработку команд одним из методов, то есть вернуть программу в начальное состояние?
Вот как это выглядит:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Один человек подсказал мне, что все дело в одинаковости третьего и четвертого хэндлера, и в данном случае надо строить конечный автомат. Честно сказать не совсем понимаю как это сделать, да и интересно узнать другие варианты решения данной проблемы.
Третий вопрос: Он исходит отсюда

> Один человек подсказал мне, что все дело в одинаковости третьего и
>   четвертого хэндлера

Я не совсем понимаю как это влияет, ведь названия функций разные, и я думал что python будет этого достаточно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратите внимание на декораторы над этими хэндлерами 
`@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])`, в параметрах которых `func`  является условием срабатывания хэндлера.

Как вариант для разрешения можно использовать следующий подход, используя метод `register_next_step_handler`
Пример:
https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py